# Compile custom package on openwrt including lib libpaho-mqtt3c

Tags: makefile, sdk, mqtt, paho, openwrt

I'm trying to compile a custom package with OpenWRT SDK.
When I compile the code, I receive this message

> fatal error: MQTTClient.h: No such file or directory  #include
> "MQTTClient.h"

I'm sure that the error is in the makefile and the not included library

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

# Name, version and release number
# The name and version of your package are used to define the variable to point to the build directory of your package: $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
PKG_NAME:=test_app
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1


# Source settings (i.e. where to find the source codes)
# This is a custom variable, used below
SOURCE_DIR:=/home/biagioscarciello/Scrivania/RUT9XX_R_GPL_00.06.07.3/test_app

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk



# Package definition; instructs on how and where our package will appear in the overall configuration menu ('make menuconfig')
define Package/test_app
    SECTION:=custom
    CATEGORY:=Custom Applications
    DEPENDS:=+libpaho-mqtt3c
    TITLE:=test_app Application
endef

# Package description; a more verbose description on what our package does
define Package/test_app/description
    test_app device -application.
endef

define Build/Configure
  $(call Build/Configure/Default,--with-linux-headers=$(LINUX_DIR))
endef
 

# Package preparation instructions; create the build directory and copy the source code. 
# The last command is necessary to ensure our preparation instructions remain compatible with the patching system.
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(Build/Patch)
endef




# Package build instructions; invoke the target-specific compiler to first compile the source file, and then to link the file into the final executable
define Build/Compile
    $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS)  -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/device_mqtt.o -c $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/device_mqtt.c -libpaho-mqtt3c
    $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS)  -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/test_app.o -c $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/test_app.c 
    $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_LDFLAGS) -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/device_mqtt.o 
    $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_LDFLAGS) -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$1 
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/test_app.o 
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/device_mqtt.o
```

endef

```
define Package/librdkafka/prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/usr/include
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/usr/lib
endef

define Package/librdkafka/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/lib
    $(CP) $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/lib/*.so* $(1)/usr/lib/
endef


# Package install instructions; create a directory inside the package to hold our executable, and then copy the executable we built previously into the folder
define Package/test_app/install
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/test_app $(1)/usr/bin
endef

# This command is always the last, it uses the definitions and variables we give above in order to get the job done
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,test_app))
```

I have also added in the feed.conf and activated this

> src-git custom https://github.com/ngohaibac/openwrt-extra-packages

that is a precompiled version of paho.

I'm not practicing with the Makefile and the SDK world.

thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `MQTTClient.h` is actually on your system?  You don't state that in your post.....because your compiler can't find it.

Comment: I have resolved using Mosquitto. Adding DEPENDS:= +libmosquitto-ssl in the Makefile and in the linking part of define Build/Compile section I have added -lmosquitto